# How to call waf configure from within a wscript

Tags: waf

I'm trying to figure out how to encapsulate the entire waf deployment process into a single waf function

Tradition waf deployment process:

```
waf distclean configure build
```

Put that into a wscript function that allows me to call all three of those waf options:

```
waf deploy
```

The function inside the wscript:

```py
def deploy(bld):
    """ Performs waf distclean, configure and build
    Args:
        bld: The waf build context object
    """
    #somehow call waf distclean, configure and build
```

requirements:
I can't do this with a shell alias; this has to be within the wscript and in python;

I've checked https://waf.io and can't find a way to call waf configure :(

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use Options from the `waflib`:

```py
def configure(conf):
    print("Hello from configure")

def build(bld):
    print("Hello from build")

def deploy(bld):

    from waflib import Options

    commands_after = Options.commands

    Options.commands = ['distclean', 'configure', 'build']
    Options.commands += commands_after
```

Comment: The right way to do it. I add `distclean` as the OP asked for the 3 commands.

Answer (score 0):

(I know that this question is quite dated; however, this is question is still one of the top suggestions to this matter.)

---

Unfortunately you cannot achieve this using 'distclean' as this command also deletes the local waflib download by `./waf`.

(Note: I am not entirely sure about this one; waf's power surprises me every day)

However, you can go for the plain 'clean':

```py
def deploy(ctx):
    from waflib import Build
    cctx = Build.CleanContext()
    cctx.execute()
```

This seems to work just fine. While we're at it:

If plan to build multiple configurations/variants/environments (i.e. Debug vs Release), you can use this little gem:

```py
def build_all(ctx):
    from waflib import Build

    deb = Build.BuildContext()
    deb.variant = 'debug' # Assuming, that 'debug' is an environment you set up in configure()
    deb.execute()

    rel = Build.BuildContext()
    rel.variant = 'release' # Analogous assumption as for debug.
    rel.execute()
```

Answer (score -1):

not the most elegant of solutions, but I'm just encapsulating the waf deployment process into a function deploy:

```py
def deploy(bld):
    import os
    os.system('waf distclean configure build_docs custom_func')
```